# To close an open shared file or folder by using a command line

Tags: windows-server-2012

i saw that there is command to close open file

```
openfiles /Disconnect /s \\filesrv /ID
```

bat it didn't worked for me 
only when i login to the server and close it from computer management.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S0kE.png)

anybody have an answer how to do it with batch command

Comment: Impossible the force-close a locally-opened file. You need to kill the process instead.

Answer (score 0):

with  user name and password

```
openfiles /Disconnect /s \\filesrv /u  /p  /ID 23488215
```

i got this message, how can i fix it

WARNING: Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, 
using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connection
to the server or shared resource and try again.